# ¿Como puedo detectar `#!` en una url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Me gustaria poder utilizar estos símbolos `#!data` en mis urls y obtener el texto después de los símbolos para mandarlo por PHP y hacer una búsqueda.
Quisiera implementar ese método con .htaccess y me gustaría saber como hacerlo.
Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: ¿No seria mejor utilizar mejor `?data=Algo`?

Comment: Lo que quiero es hacer mas sencilla la url, osea crear urls amigables al estilo de [MEGA](http://mega.nz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No es posible**, ya que las etiquetas (o fragmentos -todo lo que está después del `#`) nunca se envían al servidor. En cambio, son gestionados por el cliente.

Una alternativa es obteniéndolo con JavaScript, una vez que ya se haya accedido al recurso. Es decir, cuando ya se haya cargado la página.

En JavaScript se obtiene con [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location).

Comment: Entiendo y gracias.

Answer (score -1):

[Te recomiendo este link](http://www.emenia.es/como-crear-urls-amigables-con-htaccess/)

En tu caso seria

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^buscar/(.*)$ buscador.php?data=$1
```

Entonces pones http://ejemplo.com/buscar/AlgoComoEsto y listo.

Comment: Esto no obtendría en texto del fragmento de una URL

Comment: Tienes toda la razón es que entendí que lo queria hacer del lado del servidor.